# Closing XML files?

Tags: java, xml

So I have found a way to load a xml file.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
String filePath = stuff;
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Document document;
try {
    document = builder.parse(file);
} catch (Exception e) {}
// Start reading xml
NodeList list = document.getDocumentElement.getChildNodes();
// And here comes the algorithm to read from xml...
```

But, the problem is, this is a part of my program.
My program is designed to read a file, output its details, and then wait for user input for another xml, and continue the loop.
The reason why I raise this question is that my xml files are very large (20Mb to 50Mb) and I think the xml editors out there may fail. And upon loading the second document the first document and those loaded before are kept in the memory, and javaw.exe quickly claimed 1 Gb of memory.
Is there a way to solve this by *unloading* the document(s) from memory?

Comment: Do you need to keep the complete DOM in memory, or can you keep a more light-weight JAXB-representation or even more light-weight POJO's representing the relevant information?

Comment: When you say kept in memory, what do you mean? Your program keeps references to those documents or you feel that the XML lib is keeping it in memory though you don't need it?

Comment: I am new, both here and Xml reading, so what did all those mean?

Comment: You should add more of your code to the question so that it is possible to identify where references to the DOM trees are kept.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the streaming APIs like SAX or StAX and parse the data using events rather than loading up the whole content into memory using DOM (which is what you are doing).

However you can also try to reduce the scope of the variables by putting it inside the loop and letting the garbage collector handle it for you, but you'd still have a usage spike.